# Why this Build Error: Could not copy the file XXX to the destination file YYY because the destination is a folder instead of a file

Tags: c#-3.0, visual-studio-2019

The error is:

Could not copy the file "C:\Users\m_len\source\repos\JobAssist\src\Services\CoverLetterBankMgmt\CoverLetterBankMgmt.API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\JobAssist.Services.CoverLetterBankMgmt.API.xml" to the destination file "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\JobAssist.Services.CoverLetterBankMgmt.API.xml", because the destination is a folder instead of a file. To copy the source file into a folder, consider using the DestinationFolder parameter instead of DestinationFiles.

However when I look in the directory, the XML is there.  I deleted it and rebuilt and it was regenerated.

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 0):

One of my projects wasnt building in the solution.  I didnt figure out the cause so I just created a new project in the solution.